# Assigning values from one data frame to another based on certain rules

Tags: r, dataframe

I have one data frame in which every row is either 1 or 0 and column represents subject. Now I need to assign values from another data frame to this data frame based on the following rules.

1. Assign values subject by subject.
2. Assign the first row value from the second data frame to the first data frame.
3. Repeat the same value until the first data frame has value 1.
4. When the first data frame has value 1, assign the next value from the second data frame.

Sorry, I know this might not be clear. Please let me give an example.

1. this is what the first data frame looked like

[image]

2. this is what the second data frame looked like

[image]

3. expected result

[image]

So the number assigning to data frame 1 only change when encountering 1, the number will be the same as previous one if it is 0.

*Data sample*

**data frame 1**

```
structure(list(subject = c("subject1", "subject2"), `1` = c(0L, 
0L), `2` = 0:1, `3` = c(0L, 0L), `4` = c(0L, 0L), `5` = c(0L, 
0L), `6` = c(0L, 0L), `7` = c(0L, 0L), `8` = c(0L, 0L), `9` = c(0L, 
0L), `10` = c(0L, 0L), `11` = 1:0, `12` = c(0L, 0L), `13` = 0:1, 
    `14` = c(0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000023598771ef0>)
```

**data frame 2**

```
structure(c(0.338941353970391, 0.276963745357618, 0.271926533090457, 
0.407888635431584, 0.223490014452546, 0.313882923412051), .Dim = 2:3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do this :

```
df1 <- data.frame(df1)
df1[-1] <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(nrow(df1)), function(x) 
                  df2[x, cumsum(unlist(df1[x, -1]) == 1) + 1]))
df1

#   subject        X1        X2        X3        X4        X5        X6        X7
#1 subject1 0.3389414 0.3389414 0.3389414 0.3389414 0.3389414 0.3389414 0.3389414
#2 subject2 0.2769637 0.4078886 0.4078886 0.4078886 0.4078886 0.4078886 0.4078886

#         X8        X9       X10       X11       X12       X13       X14
#1 0.3389414 0.3389414 0.3389414 0.2719265 0.2719265 0.2719265 0.2719265
#2 0.4078886 0.4078886 0.4078886 0.4078886 0.4078886 0.3138829 0.3138829
```

I have converted the first data to dataframe. The logic is that for each row in `df1` we increment the count when we encounter 1 and use it as index to get values from the corresponding row in `df2`.